# Coldfusion 10 - Application specific classpaths

Tags: coldfusion, classloader, coldfusion-10

I am working with a CF10 application and trying to define application specific classpaths to load JARs using the `this.javaSettings`  feature [introduced in CF10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).

From Application.cfc:

```
THIS.javaSettings = {
    LoadPaths = [".\java_lib\",".\java\myjar.jar"], 
    loadColdFusionClassPath = true, 
    reloadOnChange = false
}
```

This is working great, and I can define JARs on an application basis. However, every time I reload the application (for example, if I call `applicationStop()`) then CF seems to hold on to all the loaded JARs/classes at the same time re-loading them all - which means after a number of reloads I inevitably get an out-of-memory Perm Gen error.

Has anyone experienced this? I have tried the usual things by updating GC strategies to enable permgen collection:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: How did you determine that is holding the references? I have not spent much time working with the CF10 feature, but given that is basically a rip of [Mark Mandel's JavaLoader.cfc](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?action=javaloader.index), could it be related to the old [URLClassLoader causes Memory Leak](http://www.compoundtheory.com/?ID=212&action=displayPost) issue?

Comment: I determined it by testing different permutations if setup - but basically, if i have a jar in the loadpaths settings, get a reference to that in application scope and then call applicationStop(), on the next request (when CF restarts the app) I can see the increase in permgen usage (classes not being unloaded), and this behaviour will continue until it OOMs. If I do not attempt to load any jars/classes in this way then i dont see any probs

Comment: However, I am currently looking into whether it is related to the jar in question being compiled from groovy - so CF may not be the root cause here. I will update here when I have some conclusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was not an issue with the CF feature - turns out that the memory leak was originating in the groovy code that had been compiled in to a jar (you can read groovy details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17952925/258813)

It appears as though the CF10 hot-reloading of jars is working ok!